# getting error in while calling all components in one

Tags: reactjs

hello guys i have a problem.. i have several components in my app .. i want these components in one component names as main.js and then i export this component to app.js but i am getting like this

```
./src/components/main.js
 Module not found: Can't resolve './components/join' in 
'C:\Users\Ahmad\letschat\src\components'
```

if i remove this components the same error occurs for another components .. why its coming i have no idea to resolve this kind off error because i am new in reactjs..
this is my main.js component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Login from './components/login';
import Messageonline from './components/message&online';
import SendMessage from './components/typemessage';
import Join from './components/join';



class Main extends Component {
constructor()
{
super();
this.state={temp:
[],counter:1,yourid:'',yourname:'',yourgender:'',ComingMessage:[]};
this.handleLogin=this.handleLogin.bind(this);
this.userview=this.userview.bind(this);
//this.receivingvaluefromlogin=this.receivingvaluefromlogin.bind(this);
this.going=this.going.bind(this);
this.comingmessage=this.comingmessage.bind(this);
this.handlejoin=this.handlejoin.bind(this);
// let temp = [];

}
going(id,name,gender)
{
console.log("THIS IS DONE BY REACT GEEK:",id,name,gender);
this.setState({yourid:id,
  yourname:name,
  yourgender:gender});
// console.log("THIS IS DONE BY REACT GEEKaefljhjo:",yourid);
}
async comingmessage(message)
{
console.log('here is the coming props by message box',message);
// this.setState({ComingMessage:this.state.ComingMessage.push(message)});
await this.state.temp.push(message);
this.setState({ComingMessage:this.state.temp});
 //  this.state.ComingMessage.push(message)
// console.log(this.state.ComingMessage);
}
handleLogin()
{
this.setState({counter:2});
}
handlejoin()
{
this.setState({counter:4});
console.log('this is join');
}
userview()
{
this.setState({counter:3});

console.log('are you calling');

}
 render() {
 return (

  <div className="App">
           {this.state.counter===2?
           <div >

          {/* <img src={require("../src/images/logo.png")} style=
{{maxWidth:'80vh',maxHeight:'100vh'}}alt={''}/>  */}

           <Login  show={this.userview} passingvalue={this.going} />

           </div>
           :null}
           {
             this.state.counter===1?

          <div>
      <div >
      {/* <img src={require("../src/images/logo.png")} style=
  {{maxWidth:'80vh',maxHeight:'100vh'}}alt={''}/>  */}
        </div>

        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick=
  {this.handleLogin}>Sign In</button>&nbsp;
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-info" onClick=
  {this.handlejoin}>Join Live chat</button> 
        </div>     
        :null}

  { this.state.counter===3?

          <div>

        <Messageonline LoggedInUser={{
      yourid: this.state.yourid,
      yourname: this.state.yourname,
      yourgender: this.state.yourgender
            }}  
      UserMessag={this.state.ComingMessage}/>

         <SendMessage passingmessage={this.comingmessage}/>
        </div>     
        :null}

       {this.state.counter===4?
      <div>

       <Join />
       </div>:null} 
   </div>
      );

    }
   }
   export default Main;
```

i want this component in my app.js please help me i have alot of works ahead to do but i have very short time left...its work perfectly whwn i have all this code in app.js but i want it in main.js component ...help please...thankks

Comment: pease show your file structure

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Can't resolve './components/join'` means the file "components/join.js" doesn't exist in your files structure. make sure that file exists and is at the same path. From what I see was when you moved the component from app.js to main.js that the file path is no longer valid for the join.js file.

Comment: it is valid bro...they are present in same folder call components

Comment: but that's _literally_ what the error is saying. it _can't_ be "valid"

Comment: @AhmadBilal Can you screenshot your file structure?

Comment: Glad you figured it out.